# How to scale a data using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, transform, scale, scaling

I am trying to scale my data using Python 3

But I keep getting this error: I am out of ideas as to what could be the issue? Please can you assist me guys? I would deeply appreciate your help!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import rcParams
from pylab import rcParams
import seaborn as sb

import scipy
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

import sklearn
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

mtcars = pd.read_csv('mtcars.csv')
mtcars.columns = ['Car 
names','mpg','cyl','disp','hp','drat','wt','qsec','vs','am','gear','carb']

mpg = mtcars['mpg']

#Scale your data
mpg_matrix = mpg.reshape(-1,1)
scaled = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaled_mpg = scaled.fit_transform(mpg_matrix)
plt.plot(scaled_mpg)
plt.show()


    mpg_matrix = mpg.numpy.reshape(-1,1)                                            
tr__
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.core.series.Series` doesn't have `reshape`.

Perhaps:

```
mpg_matrix = mpg.values.reshape(-1,1)
```

i.e. get the underlying `numpy` array and reshape that.

Comment: This so accurate. Thank you so much. Please, how can I know what each library contains and tackle future errors? Thank you so much

Comment: Experience, documentation and stackoverflow. :) See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape

Comment: I did this. But after doing this, my data is in array format. I can't get it back to series format. What can I do here?